# Solidity contract for other non eth erc-20 token transfer operations

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I used the official code to create a token contract，and I created a new contract. Now I hope to use this new contract to invoke token contract, transfer token from A account to B account, and encounter the problem of no transferable quota.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

interface Token {
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);   
}


/**
 * The TrxCoin contract does this and that...
 */
contract TrxCoin {

    Token token = Token(0xAc08fe3C9F442990C52904dE997D9972499bD3E6);

    function getContractAddr() view public returns (address) {
        return this;
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public {
        require(token.approve(spender, value));
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint value) public payable {
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _to, value));
    }
}
```

When I use the token contract to call the approve method directly, I can transfer through the new contract, but I can't allocate the quota directly by calling the approve method with the new contract.

Why is this? Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting this problem because you're attempting to approve the transfer of tokens from your contract, not the actual owner's address.

The ERC20 `approve` method writes to it's state that the requester is giving permission to let the spender perform the transaction. It does this with something like `allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;`.

When you are invoking the token contract (C) from your account (A), `msg.sender` is set to `address(A)`. However, when you're calling the token contract from TrxCoin, you've now introduced a new contract (B) as a middleman. The chain is now A->B->C. In this case, the `msg.sender` that C receives is now address(B). At this point, the Token contract state is still set to not allow any tokens owned by A to be transferred to `spender`.

There's no reason to delegate through the `TrxCoin` contract for the approval. Just invoke the Token contract directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I not be able to make a transfer operation if I use approre to set the address of the contract TrxCoin with the address of the address A?